# How to update firmware on Sony Walkman NW-WS413

Tags: sony

How update firmware Sony Walkman NW-WS413 from Linux Ubuntu?
wine cannot run this update

Comment: You can't. They don't provide a Linux utility.

Comment: @Pilot6 there **may** be a way... :-)

Answer (score 1):

- Install Oracle Virtualbox
- Install a Windows OS into a new VM
- In Windows, download the Sony Walkman NW-WS413 updater from [here](https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/digital-music-players-nw-nwz-ws-series/nw-ws413/downloads/W0011314)
- Connect the Sony Walkman NW-WS413 via a USB cable
- In Virtualbox, open the `Devices` menu and enable the Sony Walkman NW-WS413
- Start the Sony Walkman NW-WS413 updater
- Perform the update

Comment: I thought you were going to try to make `wine` do this!

Comment: @CharlesGreen no way :-) Wine isn't worth s**t, IMHO.

Comment: OwO ............